# At what point in the render process of a web page can we interact with that page

Tags: html, browser, rendering

I'd like to measure to distinct user experience points during the rendering of an HTML page:

1. Point which user sees the first painting of the page
2. Point at which user can interact with the page - meaning sees 75% of it or can actually register a button click or link click

I am pretty certain these UX interactions can start before the HTML code is fully rendered, so would that instance be the JS func "OnLoad" or some other distinct measureable value/function?

If it helps, we can even narrow the answer down to WebKit based browsers.

Answer (score 1):

OnLoad is a tricky thing to implement. I would suggest using a prepackaged solution like jQuerys `$(document).ready(function(){})` in order to maintain cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you just want to know when the DOM tree is loaded (which strikes me as a decent approximation of 'when we can interact with the page'), you could try the JavaScript event [DOMContentReady / 'domReady'](http://tanny.ica.com/ica/tko/tkoblog.nsf/dx/domcontentloaded-event-for-browsers).